# DFS one condition in it really confuse me

Tags: java, depth-first-search

For question:

> Given n distinct positive integers, integer k and a number
>   target. Find k numbers where sum is target. Return how many
>   solutions there are?
>
> The test case here, is A[] = {1,2,3,4}, k = 2, target = 5.
>   There are 2 solutions: [1,4] and [2,3]. 
>   So return 2.

My code is:

```
public class Solution {     
    private int res = 0;
    public int kSum(int[] A, int k, int target) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        DFS(A, k, target, 0 );
        return res;
    }

    private void DFS(int[] A, int k, int target,    int idx) {
        if (target < 0) return;
        if (k == 0) {
            if (target == 0) res += 1;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = idx; i < A.length; i++ ) {
            DFS(A, k - 1, target - A[i],  i + 1);   
            DFS(A, k,     target,         i + 1);         
        }
    }
}
```

For above code, it gives me the **output 6 (not 2)**;
**But** when I change the last 2 line from:

```
DFS(A, k - 1, target - A[i],  i + 1);   
DFS(A, k,     target,         i + 1);
```

to:

```
private void DFS(int[] A, int k, int target,  int idx,  List<Integer> temp) {

..

temp.add(A[i]);
DFS(A, k - 1, target - A[i],  i + 1,      temp);
temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
```

Then, the result becomes just right, it's 2, not 6.
I really can't tell any difference between above and below code.
Is there anyone could help me and tell me why above is wrong. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's NO need to add `"DFS(A, k,     target,         i + 1);"`
Just remove this line.

Comment: Then why, would you mind kindly explaining the reason, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Peter It's a `loop` you are using. The second line is not needed since the `loop` will try to traverse each element by `target - A[i]` & `k - 1` and the follows will also be specified by `i + 1`.